# Ubuntu 22.04 Chromium Snap Detached Mode Python Script Not Working

Tags: python, snap, chromium

I have a python (3.10) script I run from bash terminal.

The script launches Snap Chromium but occasionally I need to terminate the script using Ctrl + C, but want Chromium to remain running.

Launch Chromium in detached mode does not seem to work, when I send the interrupt the browser closes no matter which method I use.

I have tried using various combinations of commands to launch the browser including: subprocess.run, nohup, &, disown, setsid, devnull, os.system, etc.

However, the simple command: subprocess.run(browser-name &) works fine for Firefox, Edge, etc.

Please assist.

Thanks!